# Thin progress bar in action bar

Tags: android

I'm looking for any code samples containing a thin progress bar at the top of the screen, similar to [this](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/progress.html).

All I can find is info about the "regular" progress bar:

[image]

What is the thin blue progress bar called in my link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usual for new Android versions horizontal Progress Bar:

```
<ProgressBar
     style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
     ... />
```

[Here is example of customization](http://www.jagsaund.com/blog/2011/11/6/customizing-your-progress-bar-part-one.html)

Answer (score 2):

To make it thin just give your progress bar a static height eg: android:layout_height="4dp"

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the progress bar for lower Android versions using ActionBarSherlock.

The link for the source code:
http://actionbarsherlock.com/download.html

In the zip file, go to actionbarsherlock-samples -> demos.
You will get the code in "Progress.java" in the src folder.